# Mysql Create Table If Not Exists else.... Information Schema

Tags: php, mysql

Quick one hopefully - not sure where I'm going wrong here but this doesn't seem to work full stop.

Running MySQL query through PHP...

### Current code

```
$uu = mysql_query("
IF EXISTS(SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'schema_example' AND table_name = 'test_q')
THEN
insert into `test_q` (code, va_desc, price, category) 
values ('$code', '$desc', '$price', '$categ') 
on duplicate key update va_desc='$desc', price='$price', category='$categ'
ELSE
CREATE TABLE `test_quote` (
`code` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`va_desc` text NOT NULL,
`price` text NOT NULL,
`category` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
insert into `test_q` (code, va_desc, price, category) 
values ('$code', '$desc', '$price', '$categ')
END IF;
")or die(mysql_error());
```

Really appreciate some help on what I need to change, at the moment this does absolutely nothing and doesn't return any specific errors. :/

Having said that if I run it in phpMyAdmin it returns the following (although I can't understand why):

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near 
'ELSE CREATE TABLE `test_quote`(
`code` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`va_desc` text NO' at line 7
```

Comment: `IF` statements aren't SQL queries, they can only be used in stored procedures.

Comment: Aww bummer. Is there any other way round this then?

Comment: Do it as separate calls to `mysql_query()`, and perform the logic in the PHP code.

Comment: BTW, you should stop using the `mysql_*` functions, and upgade to PDO or mysqli, so you can use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: or switch to mysqli and run a multi query

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can't be done with multi-query, there's no way to do a conditional there.

Comment: @Barmar ah ok. It looked like they wanted to run mutli queries; my bad.

Comment: You don't need to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Just use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. You can use the `IF NOT EXISTS` option to `CREATE TABLE`.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_q` (
    `code` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `va_desc` text NOT NULL,
    `price` text NOT NULL,
    `category` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1");
mysql_query("insert into `test_q` (code, va_desc, price, category) 
            values ('$code', '$desc', '$price', '$categ') 
            on duplicate key update va_desc='$desc', price='$price', category='$categ'");
```

Also, a primary key is a unique key, you don't need to specify them both when you create the table.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the following query as if, else and then statements are not supported in the sql query, for that you can stored procedures.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_q` (`code` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`va_desc` text NOT NULL,
`price` text NOT NULL,
`category` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
);
mysql_query("insert into `test_q` (code, va_desc, price, category) 
        values ('$code', '$desc', '$price', '$categ') 
        on duplicate key update va_desc='$desc', price='$price', category='$categ'");
```